# Take protected (secure) pdf and save as editable (normal) pdf?

Tags: pdf, printing, print-to-pdf

Everyday, I have a script that scrapes a website and downloads daily statements as protected PDFs. This means that the PDFs are viewable, but uneditable without a password. The are read-only, if you will. I have had many requests from employees that want to edit these pdfs without opening them, clicking save as, and then re-printing the PDF to the pdf printer as a new, editable file.

Is there a solution that can mass convert these protected PDFs into editible ones? I was thinking some sort of "hot" folder where I can drop the protected pdfs into and they get auto converted and resaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GhostScript can accomplish this easily. You can download it here: http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html  In this example, I am using the 32 bit, windows version.

The following are two files. One is a powershell script and one is a batch file. The batch file will launch the powershell script and bypass any execution policy settings so that it can be run from any machine with no powershell configuration. The powershell script leverages ghostscript to reprint secure PDFs and save them as regular PDFs in a specific directory.

**Batch** (location: Q:\PDFStoPDF\convertPDF.bat)

```
cd "q:\PDFStoPDF\gs"
powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "q:\PDFStoPDF\gs\pdfconvert.ps1"
```

First, the batch changes directory to the location of the GhostScript EXE and the powershell script below. Then, it bypasses the execution policy and runs the powershell script.

**PowerShell** (location: Q:\PDFStoPDF\gs\pdfConvert.ps1)

```
$GhostScript = "q:\PDFStoPDF\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin32c.exe"

Get-ChildItem "Q:\PDFStoPDF\*.pdf" | Where {
    $_.BaseName -NotMatch "Conv"
} |  ForEach-Object {
    $InputFile = $_.FullName
    $OutputFile = "Q:\PDFStoPDF\{0} (Conv).pdf" -F $_.BaseName

    & "$GhostScript" -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="$OutputFile" "$InputFile"
}
```

The powershell script first sets the path of the GhostScript exe `gswin32c.exe`. Next, we  tell it to get all PDFs from the "Q:\PDFStiPDF\" folder where the filename does not contain the letters "conv" in order. Continuing down the pipe, we tell ghostscript that the input file will be the current filename and the output file will live in the same directory, but simply add CONV to the end of the filename.

**Before Script**: Q:\PDFStoPDF\myPDF01.pdf

**After Script** : Q:\PDFStoPDF\myPDF01Conv.pdf

The -NotMatch switch allows for files that have already been converted to be left untouched.

Next, the script prints and saves the pdf using the PDF printer `pdfwrite`

So, the steps in order to make this work are to drag a file into the Q:\PDFStoPDF\ directory and then click on the .bat file that lives there. It will take the pdf and resave it as an editable pdf in the same directory.